# How to use intermediate results in vertx future compose?

Tags: vert.x, function-composition

I am chaining some calls and I need to use the outcome of 1 future in a following call.

In the example below, what would be the most elegant way to be able to use `res1`?

```
  call1()
        .compose(res1 -> call2(res1))
        .compose(res2 -> call3(res2, res1)) // cannot user res1 here!!
        .setHandler(res -> {
            /// omitted for brevity
        });
```

I can make `call2` return a map containing `res1` and `res2` but I wonder if there is another way.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should `compose` the result of `call2` inside the lambda where `res1` is accessible:

```
call1().compose(res1 -> {
    return call2(res1).compose(res2 -> call3(res2, res1));
}).setHandler(res -> {
    // omitted for brevity
});
```